# Error in eval(object$call$data) : object '.' not found when running Anova on gls model object

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, anova, least-squares

I have successfully ran a gls on an imputed data set generated by `amelia` with the following codes

```
mod <- impute_data %>% mutate(gls_mod = data %>% purrr::map(~nlme::gls(resp_var ~ pred_var1 + pred_var2 + pred_var2), data = .)))
```

Now, I wanted to run `car::Anova` to test for the significance of each predictor variable. For this, I used:

```
Anova_mod <- mod  %>% mutate(gls.Anova = mod_gls %>% purrr::map(print(~car::Anova(.))))
```

and got the following error message:`Error in eval(object$call$data) : object '.' not found`

However, if I ran each imputed data set separately, via `car::Anova`, that works fine (But I do not want to run each data set separately). If I changed the previous code to `mod  %>% mutate(gls.Anova = mod_gls %>% purrr::map(print(~anova(.))))`
that also works fine. But, I need `car::Anova` to get type II SS. I am unable to interpret this error message. Any help on interpreting the error message would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error (using `mtcars`, see below). The `Error in eval(object$call$data) : object '.' not found` is related to the estimation of the models via `map` and stems from `data = .`. For example, switching from `.` to `.x` , i.e running `mod <- impute_data %>% mutate(gls_mod = data %>% purrr::map(~nlme::gls(resp_var ~ pred_var1 + pred_var2 + pred_var2), data = .x)))` changes the error message to `Error in eval(object$call$data) : object '.x' not found`. Put differently `car::Anova` is looking for a `data` object called `.` which it can not find. I'm quite sure that I had this problem some months ago but I can't remember how I solved it. ):

A simple solution would be to use an "old-school" for-loop to estimate the models. Using `mtcars` as example data, splitting by `cyl` and using the formula `mpg ~ hp`. Not as elegant as `map` but it works:

```
library(dplyr)

df_list <- mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl)

mod_gls_loop <- list()
for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  mod_gls_loop[[i]] <- nlme::gls(mpg ~ hp, data = df_list[[i]])  
}
Anova_gls <- mod_gls_loop %>% purrr::map(~ print(car::Anova(.)))
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>    Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
#> hp  1 3.3976    0.06529 .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>    Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
#> hp  1 0.0821     0.7745
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
#> 
#> Response: mpg
#>    Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
#> hp  1 1.0498     0.3055
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. yes, `for` loop might be the way to go. about `car::Anova` not reading (.): seems like this happens to `nlme::gls`. `Car::Anova` worked fine for `glm`, `glm.nb`. I marked your answer as correct, but cannot score you up as I have low reputation score.